# No test directory after creating a ruby gem with "bundle gem help"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, minitest

I am trying to practice TDD by creating a ruby gem.

When I create a gem using bundler I get the following file structure:

```
$ bundle gem help
Creating gem 'help'...
      create  help/Gemfile
      create  help/lib/help.rb
      create  help/lib/help/version.rb
      create  help/help.gemspec
      create  help/Rakefile
      create  help/README.md
      create  help/bin/console
      create  help/bin/setup
      create  help/.gitignore
```

However, I was expecting to be asked to install `minitest` as part of the bundle and have a `test/test_helper.rb` directory/files generated.

This is not happening and when I attempt to create them manually i.e using `mkdir test` and manually setting up a `test_helper.rb` file:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.expand_path("../../lib", __FILE__)
require "help"
require "minitest/autorun"
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!
```

I also install the correct gems in the gemfile and run bundle install.

However, after all this if I try to run: `bundle exec rake test` nothing happens!

If anyone can advise on this I would be very grateful.

Comment: `mkdire` indeed.

Comment: Can't reproduce. `bundle gem help`, then edited the `help.gemspec` file, then `bundle install` and `rspec` all work as expected. There is no default `test` task, but you can add one if desired. `bundle exec rake` does run the tests.

Comment: Fair enough, I am just confused, resources indicate a test directory is created by default and minitest can be used, just not sure why so different?

Comment: Bundler 2.1.4 generated a project with RSpec for me. Maybe it used to use MiniTest and the resources you're using are out-of-date?

Comment: Maybe, it seems resources have a hard time keeping up!